# Connecting SQL Server with Python 2.7

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to connect Python 2.7 to SQL Server to access all the tables it is currently hosting.
I am using for my official purposes so want only **legal solutions** to my problem.
Tried using a few of the solutions suggested her but none of them worked and most of them were not at all descriptive as I am new to Python.
Also is it possible to import a large table from SQL directly as a temp table(in python) and then work on it instead of accessing the DB everytime.

Details:
OS- Windows 10
DB- SQL Server 2012 (SQL server management studio)
Python- Spyder(Anaconda) for Python 2.7

thanks in advance for your help.

regards
Hitesh